# Analyzing Two likert scales

Tags: likert, scales

Our study suggests that when one persons job crafting level increases, his or her burnout level decreases.
I and my coworkers used 2 different likert scale questionnaires, one that measures job crafting and the other measures burnout. 
225 participants have answered those questionnaires.
So my question now is, how we should analyze those data, they dont fit normal distribution, which statistical test should we conduct to check our hypotesis

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to [tour], which has information for new users. Could you provide more information about the analysis? For example, how many items are in each scale? What are the response categories for questions? Why do you think non-normal distribution is an issue in this case? Maybe you could provide some descriptive plots (e.g., histograms).

Comment: "Our study suggests that when one persons job crafting level increases, his or her burnout level decreases." --- it sounds like you've already analyzed the results... What's wrong with what you did?